# How writing function pointers are better than calling them functions?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

I had pleasure of working with function pointers lately. I got to know how they work. Classical example of function pointers is :

```
int add() {
  return (100+10);
}
int sub() {
  return (100-10);
}

void print(int x, int y, int (*func)()) {
  printf("value is : %d", (x+y+(*func)()));
}

int main() {
  int x=100, y=200;
  print(x,y,add);
  print(x,y,sub);
}
```

Somebody asked me the other day that how is it better than calling(inside main):

```
print(add(x,y));
print(sub(x,y));
```

and I struggled to explain that. Is it only about the stack or there is something else lying underneath?

Comment: How about having an array of function pointers and calling them in a loop? How about having a generic interface, taking a generic type and operations on it passed as function pointers? Classical example would be `qsort`.

Comment: For one, because `add(x,y)` and `sub(x,y)` are compilable-but-worthless in C, and won't compile at all in C++ (and on that: *pick **a** language*). So the most immediate answer may well be "because that code won't compile."

Comment: Your example is not complex enough to exhibit a *bona fide* advantage to using function pointers.  Consider examples where the pointed-to function must be called at a specific point in the execution of another function, or more than one time, or with arguments chosen by the called function.

Comment: When you *can* do it without function pointers and without overcomplicating your code - don't use function pointers. At some point you will come to a situation where you will see the need of them.

Comment: `print(x,y,add);` vs. `print(x,y,add(x,y));` makes for a better comparison as `print(add(x,y));` lacks the access to use `x,y`.

Comment: The classic use of function pointers in C is `qsort()`. Alternatives that do not use a function pointer to sort imply redundant sort code only differing by the compare function or other complexities.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Point taken.

Comment: @WhozCraig. I thought it was implicit to think add/sub/print function correspondingly. I guess I should have written them explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really understand why the code you show would be a classical example of function pointers. Functions pointers' utility is much more obvious from code like this:

```
void transform(int *dst, const int *src, size_t len, int (*f)(int))
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    dst[i] = f(src[i]);
}
```

Basically, if you accept a pointer to function as a parameter, it allows you to apply a *client-provided* operation on data of *your* choice.

Comment: Aahaa. That is what I was looking for. Cool!

Should'nt it be `p[i] = f(p[i])(<some_int>)` since it accepts a parameter.

Comment: @HemantBhargava Notice that `f(p[i])` is already called on something - on `p[i]`. BTW, I modified the example to avoid confusion with `p` appearing on both sides of the assignment expression.

Answer (score 2):

The classic use case (which generalizes) is qsort (https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort). The sort algorithm is general purpose but the implementation does not know how to compare items because they can be of any type. So you pass in a function that it can call in order to compare two elements.

Answer (score 1):

Function pointers are pretty much useless overhead if you hard coded call the one or the other, like your example. Their power comes from being able to *dynamically* pick and use them, or pass them to other functions:

You can put function pointers in an array, and loop over them; or you can call a selected one *based on a user-input* or input file content, or other circumstances. In both cases, they will allow to write code that has a single dynamic call, instead of potential long switch or if statement chains.

The second - and even more useful - concept is to pass them to some other function (also sometimes called 'callbacks'); a classic example is to call `qsort` with your data table and a custom *comparison function* in form of a function pointer. qsort will then use your comparison function inside the standardized sort algorithm; there is no other way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

"pointer to function" is an object. So it can be copied,stored,assigned like any other object.
Where as references to functions (normal functions) are not objects.

I think the classic example is.... User interfaces events  handling by using callback functions, which has become an obvious pattern for any UI software.